# standard-version not counting features correctly

Tags: semantic-versioning, commitizen

I'm using conventional-changelog's [standard-version](https://github.com/conventional-changelog/standard-version) to manage semantic versioning and generate my CHANGELOG.md in my application.

I've already made my [first release](https://github.com/conventional-changelog/standard-version?tab=readme-ov-file#first-release), which means my app's version is greater than 1.0.0.

Let's suppose I have released version 1.0.3 and since then introduced 4 new features, indicated by commit messages like:

```bash
feat: feature 1
feat: feature 2
feat: feature 3
feat: feature 4
```

When running a new release:

```bash
npm run release
```

Shouldn't standard-version update my app's version from 1.0.3 to 1.4.0 since 4 new features have been introduced?

Instead, running `npm run release` yields 1.1.0. I can't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It bumps to the next *minor* version by one integer. The number of
features doesn’t matter. Only thing that matters is that:

1. You have added features
2. No breaking changes
3. Therefore bump minor version

Your current minor version in `0`. The next becomes `1`. Patch version
is reset to `0`.